# Observable subscriber.onError causes fatalException in Debug

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am calling a service within an observable and when something fails in the service I call the `subscriber.onError(error)`. In my do - onNext - onError I catch this and handle it accordingly.

My Code:

```
 return Observable.create({ subscriber -> Disposable in
        let request = self.service.request(target: xxx, success: { response in
            subscriber.onNext(response)
            subscriber.onCompleted()
        }, error: { customError in
            subscriber.onError(customError)
        }) { otherError in
            subscriber.onError(otherError)
        }

        return Disposables.create {
            request.cancel()
        }
    })
        .do(onNext: { response in
            self.doSomethingWithRespone(response)
        }, onError: { _ in
            self.doSomethingBecauseOfError()
        })
```

Yet when my code runs in Debug mode RXSwift crashes with a fatal exception on:

```
func rxFatalErrorInDebug(_ lastMessage: @autoclosure () -> String, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    #if DEBUG
    fatalError(lastMessage(), file: file, line: line)
    #else
    print("\(file):\(line): \(lastMessage())")
    #endif
}
```

I see it has a special Debug tag to execute a fatalError but I am handling the error in `onError`.
How can I prevent my code from crashing when I am already handling the error?

Comment: What was the message that the `rxFatalErrorInDebug` was outputting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused here. There are only two paths where `rxFatalErrorInDebug(_:lastMessage:file:line:)` will be called, neither of which you can cover in your code. If you attempt complete a `Single` without emitting an event or if you send an error to a `bind`.

*If* your code is causing this function to get called, just handling the error isn't good enough because you have fundamentally broken the contract of the elements involved.

If it got called because you have a `Single` that completed without emitting an element, then change it to a `Maybe`. If it got called because you passed an error to a `bind` either catch the error before the bind or change the bind into a `subscribe`.